# Execute SQL script files via PowerShell using a console app

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, powershell, connection-string

I would like to execute 3 SQL files using powershell file script and a console app.

My console app runs fine the proper "powershell script" but my problem is what I should write in my script (dbscript.ps1) to automatically execute my SQL files. I've seen several examples but neither fits in my case.

I have an ASP.NET solution and I have 3 SQL files situated in solution project (no sub-folders/ no sub-projects). Also I have a project which contains that Console App for executing my ps1 file.

What I actually need is:

*a) I have a **connection string** in `app.config` which can be used to connect to my local DB*

*b) I need to use that connection string in my `dbscript.pb1` and then I need to execute my SQL files (`s1.sql`, `s2.sql`, `s3.sql` situated right in my solution)*.

I've seen this example:

```
$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$conn.ConnectionString = "" // Here I should take my connection string from app.config
$conn.Open()
$sql = "" // Somehow I should take all my sql files (I don't know how to get the path for them)
 $cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($sql,$conn)
$rdr = $cmd.ExecuteReader()
$test = @()
while($rdr.Read())
{
    $test += ($rdr["EMP_STATUS"].ToString())
}
Write-Output $test
```

So, *how* can I get that *connection string* from `app.config` and how can I set all the sql files to be executed in a specific order?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just connect to the DB to run the scripts? Why deal with running them through powershell?

Comment: Because in the future I'll handle about 20-25 scripts. Do you think it is a reliable way to do it? Why not trying to do them automatically?

Comment: If that is the case just keep them as .sql files and not powershell. Name them in a certain way that you can change it's order OR create an XML file you will read and execute them in the order you have specified.

Comment: Have you done any investigation into how to use PowerShell? It looks like you only need to use `Get-Content` to complete the script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not what you are asking but I would do it this way just because it seems like more of a headache to deal with powershell when you are already writing an app that will do this for you.

```
//get application path and script directory
private const string scriptPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "Scripts");

private void RunScripts()
{
    string[] scripts = Directory.GetFiles(scriptPath, "*.sql", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
    //name them script01.sql, script02.sql ...etc so they sort correctly
    Array.Sort(scripts);

    if (scripts.Length > 0)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionStringKey"]))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                foreach (string script in scripts)
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = File.ReadAllText(script);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for a nice option. But I cannot accept it because my question was about PowerShell. However, cool.

Comment: @shemuel When you create your connection string just use master as the DB or in your script you can use 'use master' and have your script switch it.

Answer (score 0):

Then the reason is number of .sql files. Well you can use a .bat only. Even you can order you .sql files in subfolder and put the .bat file in the root of the container folder:

```
C:\MySqlScripts
    |
    |_RunAllSqlFiles.bat
    |
    |_Functions
    |    |
    |    |_Function_1.sql
    |
    |_StoredProcedures
         |
         |_StoredProc_1.sql
```

The .bat file will execute all .sql files recursively, here the content of RunAllSqlFiles.bat file:

```
@echo off
ECHO %USERNAME% process started at: %TIME%  >output.txt

for /R %%i in (*.sql) do (
sqlcmd.exe -S tcp:SERVER_INSTANCE,1433 -E -d DB_NAME -i "%%i"  >>output.txt
)
pause
```

You must change SERVER_INSTANCE and DB_NAME. That .bat uses [sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) and Windows authentication

So with that .bat a double click is enough.